# Blender crashes on right click, don't know how to update driver

Tags: crash, intel-graphics, gpu

Whenever I right click something to select it, Blender crashes. I did some searching to see why, and it is apparently due to faulty graphics drivers. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to update them.

I am on Linux Mint (64 bit), and I have an Intel graphics card.

Answer (score 2):

As a temporary solution, open Blender's User Preferences and go to the system tab. Change "Selection render mode" to "OpenGL occlusion queries." This fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Great, this fixed the crashes for me, thank you so much! Do you have any insight on what this options actually does? Are there any drawbacks to setting it?

Comment: I think it's just selecting a newer interface that's better supported by the driver.